# Standardised plot of multiple points with varying thresholds and values

Tags: visualization, plotting

I would like to plot the points below to show which points are inside their thresholds and which are outside their thresholds.

[image]

I intend to do another set of analysis with other parameters which will change the values of all columns except for Point.

The reason I want to do this is so I can have a visual representation at a high level of how changing parameters results in better performance (more in bounds) or worse performance (more outside bounds).

The best I can come up with is setting each point to a ratio of their bounds, but I cannot figure out what I would put on the x axis here, maybe the Point column?

What other options would I have at my disposal to be able to visually represent this data? (at a high level).

[image]

Comment: I guess you could put any feature on the x-axis, especially if you suspect a feature can be correlated to the point being in- or out-of-bounds. For instance, you could put the amplitude MaxThreshold-MinThreshold on the x-axis, to see whether points that have a larger bounding interval tend to more easily be in their interval.

Comment: yeah good point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to put the "Point" column on the x-axis and the percent on the y-axis. Given that the "Point" column is a nominal level of measurement, the x-axis has to be consistent with that (e.g., bar chart). The y-axis / percent is a numeric level of measurement from -25% to +300%. "Inside bounds" can be represented by color (i.e., green and red).